# cant assign values to file variable

Tags: c, arrays, gtk

im quite new to C, and im trying to populate a file wide array variable with the results of a function, heres a simple code sample to show what i mean, can anyone point me in the direction of why this doesnt work?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>

static gchar *external_names;

void directories(int arraylength, gchar internal_names[][100]){
    int n;
    for (n = 0; n < arraylength; n++)
    {
        strcpy(external_names[n], internal_names[n]);
    }
    for (n = 0; n < arraylength; n++)
    {
        printf("%s internal with %s external\n",internal_names[n], external_names[n]);
    }
}

void main()
{
    gchar anotherarray[10][100];
    directories(10, anotherarray);
}
```

[EDIT] latest code

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>

static gchar *external_names[100];

void directories(int arraylength, gchar internal_names[][100]){
    int n = 0;
    //gchar external_names[arraylength][100];
    for (n = 0; n < arraylength; n++)
    {
        printf("%s %i\n","before", n);
        strcpy(external_names[n], internal_names[n]);
        printf("%s %i\n","after", n);
    }
}

void main()
{
    int n;
    gchar anotherarray[10][100];
    for (n = 0; n < 10; n++)
    {
        strcpy(anotherarray[n],"test");
    }
    directories(10, anotherarray);
    for (n = 0; n < 10; n++)
    {
        printf("%s internal with %s external\n",anotherarray[n], external_names[n]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're writing to an indeterminate address in memory through that pointer; not a file. Use the FILE apis form the C runtime library, starting with [`fopen()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen), [`fprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), and [`fwrite()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite), etc. That will hopefully get you started.

Comment: You can't use the value of a variable until you assign it one. You use `external_names` (in this code: `strcpy(external_names[n], internal_names[n]);`) before you assign it any value.

Comment: im not trying to write to a file, just a file wide(static) variable, does     'strcpy(external_names[n], internal_names[n]);)'    not assign the value of internal_names[n] to the external array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static gchar *external_names;  //one dimensional array.
```

**external_names** is a one dimensional array and you are trying to assign it from a two dimensional array **internal_names**.

```
strcpy(external_names[n], internal_names[n]);
```

This is what happens when you increment the index.

```
&internal_names[1] =  &internal_names[0] + size_t*100
&external_names[1] =  &external_names[0] + size_t*1
```

To solve this,

```
static gchar (*external_names)[100];
```

should work.

Comment: ah ok, so id want to declare it as static gchar *external_names[]; i guess?

Comment: with 'static gchar *external_names[100];' the code segfaults at strcpy(external_names[n], internal_names[n]); due to the external array being uninitialized, but if i initialize it inside the block it doesnt seem to get the values, ive added the updated code to the original post to show what i mean

Comment: @Mike You should get some answer from the accepted answer of this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901962/strcpy-and-arrays-of-strings

Comment: thanks again sibrajas, that helped a bunch :)

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
static gchar *external_names;
```

is just a single character pointer, it's not an array of strings like your `anotherarray`.

When you index in your `strcpy()` call, the first argument is a `char` which is wrong since `strcpy()` expects two pointers.